# Zend framework: "url not found" only with index controller, only if lowercase

Tags: zend-framework, controller, indexing, http-status-code-404, uppercase

This is my problem:

I have a working zend application running on aruba/linux.
It seems to work well.

I have some controllers: index, user, video, ...

if i type "http://www.foo.com/public/" i can reach my index controller and index action.
if i type "http://www.foo.com/public/user/register" i can reach my user controller and register action.

if i type "http://www.foo.com/public/index/index" the server return url not found :(

But the most strange thing is that if i type "http://www.foo.com/public/Index/index" (pay attention on the UPPERCASE I) it works.

I try an explanation, but i don't found it :(

Can you help me??

Thanks in advance, Gabriele.

PS: in locale on my computer it works well

---

UPDATE

a behavior that i didn't notice this afternoon: if i call a controller that doesn't exist zend show the custom error page with write that there isn't the specified controller. With the index controller i obtain instead 404: url not found...

i absolutely don't know what to do... please help me!!

---

RE-UPDATE

I've changed the default controller from 'index' to 'foo', i have renamed all files, classes and folder correctly and the application works well, without this stupid error...

It seems that the 'index' word creates some kind of bug..
It's a kind of magic...

Comment: local = windows? if yes check names of your controller. IndexController.php / and Class: IndexController extends..

Comment: Sorry if i didn't write it: i'm on a mac under apache server!! So it is as on linux... the names are exactly as you write!

Comment: is there something in your error log??

Comment: yes, there is this line: [Tue Feb 07 09:49:09 2012] [error] [client 87.2.***.***] Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /web/htdocs/www.***.com/home/public/index (None could be negotiated).

Comment: Check your httpd.conf for: Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews and remove MultiViews if configured

Comment: I'm in aruba linux shared, so i can't see the httpd.conf file...

Comment: However i have just tried to set the multiviews option in my locale server, but the application still working correctly!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

The problem was in my Virtual host setting.
I had the following settings in my Directory of my Virtual host:

```
<Directory /home/koen/zend/ZendCMS/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I put a dash in front of MultiViews and that fixed the problem.

Like this:

```
<Directory /home/koen/zend/ZendCMS/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: If this helped you work out your problem, please accepts it as the answer :)

Comment: You can also just remove the `MultiView` option, it is off by default. In my apache2.4 I needed to put `+` or `-` to all options, if I wanted to exclude `MultiViews` explicit

Answer (score 3):

Try to change your index url to Index/index rather than index/index
apache2 by default in some configurations picks index as a default index.* file available in the document root

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when I upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4.  I basically copied over the httpd-vhosts.php file from one version to the next (after making the changes listed in the upgrade guide).  My site worked fine for every page except /index, though the homepage would load if I left that off.

The answer provided by ArneRie in the original response thread is what resolved it for me.  Removing MultiViews from the conf file cleared up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed "/index" to "/Index" and it worked

Comment: can you explain a bit more? what was the cause of the problem, strictly a case sensitive directory?

Answer (score 0):

I had simillar problem today.

All other controllers works, also routes to index controller like this:

```
    $router->addRoute("object", 
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex("object/(\d+)",
            array(
                "controller" => "index",
                "action"     => "object"
            )
        )
    );
```

works too.

But the /index/object show the 404 file not found error.

Must be something with the Options in vhost settings. I removed them totally and it helped in my case.

P.S.: Also you can direct your vhost on public folder so your links would look like: http://www.foo.com/user/register rather than http://www.foo.com/public/user/register