# IndexController retrive 404 ERROR but other controllers work fine

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've installed Zend Framework(version 1.12) on localhost and I have a problem with accesing actions from IndexController but same code, same actions names are working perfectly fine in other controllers let's say TestController.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
public function init(){/* Initialize action controller here */}
public function indexAction(){//some code}
public function addAction(){//some code}
public function otherAction(){//other code}
}

class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
public function init(){/* Initialize action controller here */}
public function indexAction(){//some code}
public function addAction(){//some code}
public function otherAction(){//other code}  
}
```

When I type in address bar zf.local/ I recive content from index/index.phtml file but when I type zf.local/index/index ZF tell that url is not find. When I type zf.local/test/index everything is working fine
If I type in address bar zf.local/index/add I recive a 404 ERROR but if I type zf.local/test/add everything is working fine.

I've set my virtual host to AllowOverride All, and I enabled rewrite module from Apache.I stop, restart and reload apache, restart my pc.I think that is no problem with apache, or virtual host that is why I am writing this.[My apache and virtual host configurations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276871/getting-started-with-zend)

Once I tried to type zf.local/default/index/add and the code is working so I need to put a /default before /index in address bar

I think that this could be solved with Zend helper to insert in my url /default before /index
[Official DOcumentation form Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) but I don't know how to do it. Until now I've manage to get only bugs

From index.html I call actions from controller with next code :

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'add'));
    ?>">Add</a>
```

Comment: Another question with the same problem as mine:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161455/zend-framework-url-not-found-only-with-index-controller-only-if-lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You ZF Application is incorrect created. Try first to create application from command line. After that this problem shall be solved.

Comment: I created my Zend project from command line with  zf create project zf command. Here is the output robotzi@ubuntu:/var/www$ zf create project zf
Creating project at /var/www/zf
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README
Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created. Still after that I created a new  project from existing source (zf) in netbeans could this be a prbolem?

Comment: If so, check your routes.php or Bootstrap.php files. Maybe there was created some code, that overwrites default routes. In Default package, even if you have modules, you can access to actions with MVC pattern as /<skip module if default>/<controller>/<action>/

Comment: My Bootstrap.php is empty. U said something about default package and modules can explain a little bit ot me what to do with them?

Comment: Please check this article. If you follow _all_ steps, no problems should occur.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

Comment: I build my project after that article. Here is my project [URL=http://www.filehost.ro/29420452/ZendExample_zip/]ZendExample zip[/URL]

Comment: ZF is configured correct. I've managed to run you app, and opened link /index/index

Problem should be in some other place...

Comment: When I press Run from netbeans my project start and in address bad apears zendexample.local/ and on screen I recive rome rows from a database. But when I set a link to access index controller action "add" i recive a 404 error, but if a access with a link test controller action "add"  Is working

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the view file to get the correct url

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'default', 'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'add'));
?>">Add</a>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and is not working to me. When I access an action from IndexController the link is still http://zendexample.local/index/add(NO DEFAULT before index). Here is mmy project puloaded online http://www.filehost.ro/29420452/ZendExample_zip/]ZendExample